# SQL in Excel: Cannot call declared variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to breakdown my SQL string in Excel VBA, storing my variables in the first part of the SQL, and calling them in the second part. It seems that declared variables is not my friend here?

**First part(Declaring my variable)**

```
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim sSQL As String

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rst.LockType = adLockReadOnly
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.CommandTimeout = GCL_dbTimeout

cnn.Open "XXX"
rst.ActiveConnection = cnn

sSQL = "DECLARE @Id AS INT = 1234 ; SELECT @Id AS [Id] INTO #cte_TEMP;"
cnn.Execute (sSQL)
```

**Second part(Calling my variable)**

Using a temp table works:

```
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM #cte_TEMP;"
```

But calling the variable doesn't:

```
rst.Open "SELECT @Id;"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-memory `@variables` are only in-scope during the execution of a single command; once `rst.Open` returns, the variable is gone and no longer exists.

By storing it into a `#temp` table, you are persisting the value to physical disk storage, which leaves it available to other subsequent commands.

Don't forget to `DROP TABLE #cte_TEMP;` at one point! :)

Note: `#temp` tables are only accessible from the user that created it. If you need to access it from a different connection string, you need to use `##temp` tables instead.

Comment: that makes me sad because I very much prefer to use @variable. thanks anyway.

Comment: @twenty49 then consider consuming the variables in the same command that creates them, if that's possible. It's unclear from your post *why* they need to be separate commands.